# pyfftw - wheels fail to build because fftw libraries cannot be found

Tags: python, macos, pip, fftw, pyfftw

I've been trying to install FFTW and pyFFTW libraries on my macbook. I've managed to install the FFTW library via homebrew, and it is currently stored in the directory /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw

However, when I try to run `pip install pyfftw` I run into the following error (copy pasted from terminal; shortened it for simplicity but please let me know if the earlier information is needed):

```
  /var/folders/tq/nyll_l_92r94p57ry8z60bd80000gq/T/pyfftw-yym3ktj2/fftwl_plan_dft.c:2:17: error: call to undeclared function 'fftwl_plan_dft'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                  fftwl_plan_dft();
                  ^
  1 error generated.
  WARNING:__main__:Compilation error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  DEBUG:__main__:clang -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/[username]/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/[username]/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/include/ -I/private/var/folders/tq/nyll_l_92r94p57ry8z60bd80000gq/T/pip-install-wh14p0su/pyfftw_18d0e6b0f22d4654ba518a114fb808e0/include -I/private/var/folders/tq/nyll_l_92r94p57ry8z60bd80000gq/T/pip-install-wh14p0su/pyfftw_18d0e6b0f22d4654ba518a114fb808e0/pyfftw -I/private/var/folders/tq/nyll_l_92r94p57ry8z60bd80000gq/T/pip-build-env-3le0qyfi/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/[username]/anaconda3/include -I/Users/[username]/anaconda3/include/python3.11 -c /var/folders/tq/nyll_l_92r94p57ry8z60bd80000gq/T/pyfftw-yym3ktj2/fftwl_plan_dft.c -o /var/folders/tq/nyll_l_92r94p57ry8z60bd80000gq/T/pyfftw-yym3ktj2/fftwl_plan_dft.o
  
  DEBUG:__main__:Checking for fftwl_plan_dft...no
  DEBUG:__main__:{'HAVE_DOUBLE': False, 'HAVE_DOUBLE_OMP': False, 'HAVE_DOUBLE_THREADS': False, 'HAVE_DOUBLE_MULTITHREADING': False, 'HAVE_DOUBLE_MPI': False, 'HAVE_SINGLE': False, 'HAVE_SINGLE_OMP': False, 'HAVE_SINGLE_THREADS': False, 'HAVE_SINGLE_MULTITHREADING': False, 'HAVE_SINGLE_MPI': False, 'HAVE_LONG': False, 'HAVE_LONG_OMP': False, 'HAVE_LONG_THREADS': False, 'HAVE_LONG_MULTITHREADING': False, 'HAVE_LONG_MPI': False, 'HAVE_MPI': False}
  error: Could not find any of the FFTW libraries
  [end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyfftw Failed to build pyfftw ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyfftw, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've tried setting temporary environment variables, which were

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/lib/
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/lib/"
export CFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/include/"
```

prior to running this, so I'm not sure where the error might be coming from. I've been looking at the installation guide online linked [here](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW#mac-osx).

Additionally, when calling `locate libfftw`, it says that there are libraries installed in directory /opt/homebrew/lib/. If go down the directory by hand, the directory is /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/lib/, and the libraries are present there as well.

Comment: Is this an ARM Mac? This is still a WIP: https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/issues/316#issuecomment-1715720032

Comment: @HenryGomersall ooh, yeah I'm using Mac M1